# Trouble answering a python syntax challenge

Tags: python

I received this challenge where if I run the code right, a flag should appear. A little disclaimer, my Python skills are rough to non-existent and I'll be glad to understand what is causing the syntax errors in the code, specifically when trying to run the line 15 "31/21" seems to cause the problem, but here's the code:

```
str = '''
 _____       _                 _____                   _ 
/  __ \     | |               |_   _|                 | |
| /  \/_   _| |__   ___ _ __    | | ___ _ __ __ _  ___| |
| |   | | | | '_ \ / _ \ '__|   | |/ __| '__/ _` |/ _ \ |
| \__/\ |_| | |_) |  __/ |     _| |\__ \ | | (_| |  __/ |
 \____/\__, |_.__/ \___|_|     \___/___/_|  \__,_|\___|_|
        __/ |                                            
       |___/       
       '''


print(str)
print("Congratulations on Completing Your Challenge!\n")
print("Please send your CV, the code "31/21" and your registered email to the challenge via our Email address: cyberm@cyber.gov.il\n")
input("Stay safe ;)")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Escape "31/21" as \"31/21\". The quotes are completing the string.

Comment: And you should rename your `str` variable. It conflicts with a built in function.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 2):

When you want a `"` character in a string you can use the single quote `'` to delimit the whole string:

```py
print('Please send your CV, the code "31/21" and your registered email to the challenge via our Email address: cyberm@cyber.gov.il\n')
```